# BulletPhysics - Update single objects

Tags: c#, c++, bulletphysics

I am using Bullet Physics as my physics engine. The problem I have currently is that I cannot find how (or if) I can stepSimulate a single body/object in a DiscreteDynamicsWorld. I want to basicly say something like this:

```
World->StepSimulateSingleBody(body, elapsedTime);
```

rather than the usual:

```
World->StepSimulation(elapsedTime...);
```

So is there even such a thing? I went through Bullet documentation and I saw that their single step simulation func is internal - so I wonder if there is another way to do this.

I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I couldn't find the answer elsewhere.

P.S. I am actually using the latest version of BulletSharp because I am programming in C# but both C++ and C# answers will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off asking at http://www.bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=9 , but in general there is no way to step a single body in the dynamics world. If you can explain what you're trying to achieve maybe I can help a bit more.